# Mapping between actual signer and delegated signer

Tags: docusignapi

I have integrated DocuSign APIs with my application. DocuSign provides feature to assign signing responsibility to someone else. When I try to get the status of all the recipients I am unable to identify which signer delegated his responsibility to which signer.

```
    {
       "witnesses": [],
       "seals": [],
       "intermediaries": [],
       "currentRoutingOrder": "1",
       "carbonCopies": [{
             "requireIdLookup": "false",
             "recipientId": "1",
             "status": "completed",
             "email": "charles@gmail.com",
             "recipientIdGuid": "15e02ae9-a4cb-4562-a05f-381d9d555894",
             "userId": "0e6e3f29-6f69-4b48-92a1-be7443b0ac58",
             "name": "Charles Kom",
             "routingOrder": "1"
        }],
        "agents": [],
        "recipientCount": "2",
        "signers": [{
             "requireIdLookup": "false",
             "recipientId": "155500",
             "creationReason": "sender",
             "status": "sent",
             "email": "anna@gmail.com",
             "recipientIdGuid": "405ccc6e-b6b4-4d7a-b21a-cfab853a8499",
             "userId": "521911fd-3215-4a83-93f3-7a62991ca64d",
             "name": "Anna",
             "routingOrder": "1",
             "identityVerification": {},
             "note": "sdfsae",
             "isBulkRecipient": "false"
        }],
        "editors": [],
        "inPersonSigners": [],
        "certifiedDeliveries": []
     }
```

This is the response I receive from API. Here there is no mean to find which signer delegated responsibility to whom if I have more than one signers and more than one have delegated.

Is there any other API to find out this thing?

One possible solution I thought is DocuSign also has feature of View Envelope History. But I couldn't found any REST API for that.

Answer (score 0):

`GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/audit_events` is the API call to get the envelope audit history. On check the response, you will the `Action` as `Reassign` and Message also will have Original Signer and new Signer's name and email address.

```
{
            "name": "Action",
            "value": "Reassign"
        },
        {
            "name": "Message",
            "value": "John Smith reassigned the envelope to Daisy Duck [daisyduck+delegate@gmail.com] routing order 1"
        }
```

[DS Docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listAuditEvents) has more details about this API.